# Representing whole numbers as $a^2 + b^2 + 4ab$ for integers $a,b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Lets say it's $18$. Is there a way to be sure that this number can definitely be represented like $$a^2 + b^2 + 4ab$$

The problem mainly arises due to the $4ab$ and not $2ab$, otherwise only perfect squares could be possible. Ideas anyone? Please help.

Comment: Try with $a^2+b^2+4ab=(a+2b)^2-3b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^2+b^2+4ab=(a+2b)^2-3b^2$.
Moreover, if $18$ can be written in this form then also $2$ can be written in this form.
Indeed $(a+2b)^2-3b^2=18$ implies that both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $3$, thus if $a=3u$ and $b=3v$ then $(u+2v)^2-3v^2=2$.
But $2$ is not a square modulo $3$, thus the answer is no.

Comment: I'm sorry for the doubts but, since I'm not very smart, how can we imply that 2 can be written in this form and both a and b are divisible by 3?

Comment: Write $18+3b^2=(a+2b)^2$. Left hand side is divisible by $3$, hence   by $9$ because it's a square. But $9|18$, hence $9|3b^2$, hence $3|b$. But also $3|(a+2b)$, thus $3|a$. By substituting $a=3u$ and $b=3v$ and collecting $9$ you obtain $(u+2v)^2-3v^2=2$.

Comment: Another doubt :P, What if the number (18 in this case) is prime, like 11? What do I do then?

Comment: Since $11\equiv 2\pmod 3$ you can say directly that it's not representable in this form.

Comment: seems I keep losing you, this is what I do get 
>  $$a^2+b^2+4ab = (a+2b)^2−3b^2$$
>  now we take the assumption that (a+2b)^2−3b^2 = 11
>  from here how you get to 11≡ 2 (mod 3) I don't get it :/

Comment: You obtain $11\equiv (a+2b)^2\pmod 3$, but $11$ is not a square modulo $3$, so that this is impossible.

Comment: Wonderful, everything is clear now. I cant tell you how much i appreciate your help. Thank you again :)